# Nancy 500 server error with dotnetcore and kestrel

Tags: .net-core, nancy, dotnet-cli

I am trying to use NancyFX (clint-eastwood) with `dotnetcore1.1` and `dotnet-cli 1.0.0-rc4-004771`. My current project structure is -

```
CustomBootstrapper.cs
HomeModule.cs
index.sshtml
nancyapp.csproj
Program.cs
Startup.cs
```

And codes are -

## nancyapp.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Nancy">
      <Version>2.0.0-clinteastwood</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

## Program.cs

```cs
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace nancyapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

## Startup.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Nancy.Owin;

namespace nancyapp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseOwin(x => x.UseNancy());
        }
    }
}
```

## HomeModule.cs

```cs
using Nancy;

namespace nancyapp
{
    public class HomeModule : NancyModule
    {
        public HomeModule()
        {
            Get("/", _ => { return View["index.sshtml"]; });
            Get("/test/{name}", args => new Person() { Name = args.name });
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## index.sshtml

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    Welcome to Nancy App.
</body>
</html>
```

`CustomBootstrapper.cs` is currently empty.

When I try to access `Get("/test/{name}", args => new Person() { Name = args.name });` from a rest client i get the expected result.

However, when I try to access to root or `Get("/", _ => { return View["index.sshtml"]; });`, I get a `500` server error saying -

> Error details are currently disabled. To enable it, please set
>   TraceConfiguration.DisplayErrorTraces to true. For example by
>   overriding your Bootstrapper's Configure method and calling
>   environment.Tracing(enabled: false, displayErrorTraces: true)

I tried following the instruction in the error message and enable error tracing by including the following code in `CustomBootstrapper.cs`

```cs
protected override void ApplicationStartup(Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
{
    var environment = GetEnvironment();
    environment.Tracing(true, true);
}
```

But then I get the following error when trying to run the application with `dotnet run`

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same
  key has already been added. Key: Nancy.TraceConfiguration at
  System.ThrowHelper.ThrowAddingDuplicateWithKeyArgumentException(Object key) at 
  System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key,TValue value, Boolean add) at
  nancyapp.CustomBootstrapper.ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines) in D:\TempWork\nancyapp\CustomBootstrapper.cs:line 17 at
  Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperBase`1.Initialise() at
  Nancy.Owin.NancyMiddleware.UseNancy(NancyOptions options) at
  Nancy.Owin.DelegateExtensions.UseNancy(Action`1 builder, NancyOptionsoptions) at 
  nancyapp.Startup.<>c.<Configure>b__0_0(Action`1 x) in D:\TempWork\nancyapp\Startup.cs:line 10 at
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.OwinExtensions.UseOwin(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 pipeline) at
  nancyapp.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) in D:\TempWork\nancyapp\Startup.cs:line 10
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
  System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) at
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication() at
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build() at
  nancyapp.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\TempWork\nancyapp\Program.cs:line 11
```

I am not sure what's causing the error or how to enable tracing. Can anyone help?

Comment: What happen when you try to access the `url` from a browser? Please show the code for `GetEnvironment`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The are two problems here :

- The 500 is because the view was not found , what you need to do is provide a root path by implementing `IRootPathProvider` and return `Directory.GetCurrent()`.
- Secondly to enable tracing you need `public override void Configure(INancyEnvironment environment)` this adds the keys hence you the exception you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You may get the same server error (500) when using Nancy in a **.NET Core 3.1** app in combination with `Owin >= v3`.

- I've solved the issue by **downgrading** `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin` from v3.x to **v2.2.0.**

My running setup was the following after the downgrade:

[image: Setup]

It's also fine to return a simple text for testing:

```cs
Get("/", _ => { return new TextResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello world!"); });
```